# aws amplify graphql computed field inline resolver

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

For complex field resolver, I know [@function directive](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#function) is the way to go.

But how about those very simple computed fields. @function directive with lambda is a little too much. I see prisma has inline javascript function supported. see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033761/1443505) of similar quest.

Not sure whether aws-amplify graphql support inline function.

Comment: You can use VTL custom resolvers, but there is a lot of boilerplate: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/resolvers#overwriting-resolvers

Comment: It's true, AppSync is missing a little something, JavaScript functions.  VTL is kinda like Java.  Possibly write the function in Java VTL.  Can you explain how short the inline function is?  I don't know.  I like AppSync.  Efforts to use AppSync shouldn't go to waste.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default VTL resolver for the field, just adding the logic you want.

[This article](https://www.fullsapps.com/2019/03/aws-amplify-overriding-auto-generated.html) goes into detail on a simple use case (similar to yours I think)

Just a few steps

- Add the field to your schema
- Build your API
- Look for the auto-generated resolver (`amplify/backend/api/client/build/resolvers`) The naming convention is straight-forward.
- Copy it to `amplify/backend/api/client/resolvers`
- Change it as needed
- Push your changes to Amplify

In the article he has just added a new set item

```
## [Start] Prepare DynamoDB PutItem Request. **
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("createdAt", $util.time.nowISO8601()))
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("updatedAt", $util.time.nowISO8601()))
# The next line was added
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("active", false))
```

AWS has some [tutorials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-programming-guide.html) over VTL that you might want to take a look.

And Amplify has more [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/resolvers#overwriting-resolvers) on custom resolvers using VTL